# TSQL - dynamic Pivot on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

In below screenshot you see my source and desired output table.

I cannot hardcode the columns "Product", "Year" or "Measure" as they can grow dynamically. Columns "1", "2" and so on represent a month, which can be hardcoded.

[image]

I would be happy if you could show me a dynamic query or point me to a similar solution.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/82bb4/5) of the source.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you succeed unpivoting months? Did you succeed "hardcoded" pivoting of single column?

Comment: What's your expect result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
--Data
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test

CREATE TABLE test
    ([Product] varchar(5), [Year] varchar(4),[Measure] varchar(10), 
     [1] int, [2] int, [3] int, [4] int,[5] int, [6] int,[7] int, [8] int,[9] int, [10] int,[11] int, [12] int)
;

INSERT INTO test
    ([Product], [Year], [Measure], [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
VALUES
    ('ABCD', '2017','efgh', 1, 11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,100,110),
    ('ABCD', '2017','efgh', 2, 12,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,100,110),
    ('ABCD', '2018','mnop', 3, 13,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,100,110),
    ('ABCD', '2018','mnop', 4, 14,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,100,110),
    ('WXYZ', '2017','efgh', 5, 15,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,100,110),
    ('WXYZ', '2017','efgh', 6, 16,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,100,110),
    ('WXYZ', '2018','mnop', 7, 17,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,100,110),
    ('WXYZ', '2018','mnop', 8, 18,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,100,110)
;

--UNPIVOTING MONTHS (As fixed months that is why using non-dynamic unpivot)
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP
SELECT Product, [Year], Measure, [Month], [Value]
INTO TEMP
FROM
(
  SELECT Product, [Year], Measure
  ,[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]
   FROM test
) AS t
UNPIVOT
(
  [Value] FOR [Month] IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
 ) AS up;

select * from test

--Dynamic  Pivoting
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols = STUFF(
                 (
                     SELECT DISTINCT 
                            ','+ Measure
                     FROM TEMP c FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');
print @cols
SET @query = 'SELECT Product, Year, [Month], '+@cols+' from 
                (SELECT 
                   Product,
                   Year,
                   [Month],
                   [Value],
                   Measure AS Category
                FROM TEMP
                )x 
                pivot 
                (
                    sum([Value]) for Category in ('+@cols+')
                ) p
                order by 1,2, convert(int, [Month])';
print @query
EXECUTE (@query);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. I was able to get it to run in my enviroment.